# How to use the primitive \the with dimen?

Tags: programming

I know that I need to put an internal quantity after `\the`. I know the expansion is a list of tokens of catcode 12 (except for space characters).
I know the next problem :

```
\skip0=30pt plus 2pt\relax
a\hskip\the\skip0 minus 1pt b 
a\hskip\skip0 b  
a\hskip\skip0 minus 1pt b
```

but in the sources of pgf/tikz, I see for example

```
\def\pgfgetlastxy#1#2{%
    \edef#1{\the\pgf@x}%
    \edef#2{\the\pgf@y}%
}%
```

`\pgf@x` is often preceded by `\the`. Why is `the` necessary in such cases?
Do you know an example with a problem ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` registers are temporary ones which are changed frequently. Using `\the` inside `\edef` stores the *current value* of them *as string* into a *normal macro*, so that value(s) can still be used elsewhere after the registers are already changed again.

Simply using `\def#1{\pgf@x}` would make the macro given as `#1` a synonym for `\pgf@x` which would not give you any benefits.